# Imagecreatefrompng problem

Tags: php

I took code from the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)

```
function LoadPNG($imgname)
{
    $im = @imagecreatefrompng($imgname);

    if(!$im)
    {
        $im  = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 30);
        $bgc = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $tc  = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

        imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 150, 30, $bgc);

        imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, 'Error loading ' . $imgname, $tc);
    }

    return $im;
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');

$path = './upload/xxx.png';
$img = LoadPNG($path);

imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

and I have message in browser and page doesn't load:

No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

But if I change imagecreatefrompng to imagecreatefromjpeg, imagepng to imagejpeg and path to jpeg file. Or write incorect file I have error image (imagestring) - it works fine...

Comment: How big (resolution) is the PNG image that you are dealing with (`./upload/xxx.png`)?

Comment: Buggabill has posted a good answer to help you debug your problem. On another note though, examples posted on php.net aren't there to simply take and use exactly. They are usage *examples* and should be used to *help* you write your own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a memory issue.  I would change this line

```
$im = @imagecreatefrompng($imgname);
```

to this

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng($imgname);
```

You may get some more information if you do that.  Just change it back when you put this code into production.  Your users do not need to see any warnings and errors.  If it is a memory issue, that same section where you got the code has [this tidbit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php#73546) of information.

Comment: What is the resolution of the picture that you are using?  The default memory setting may be too low for a larger image on your server.  PNG images apparently need a bit more memory than jpegs to process.

Comment: dimensions: 602 x 526, size: 29,7 KB (30 514 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

See there - http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=21542